# Optimistic locking by correlationId in event store

Tags: eventstoredb

How do you achieve optimistic locking by correlationId in EventStoreDB? As I saw in the documentation revision/version is only supported per stream, and putting correlationId in the stream name is bad practice and should affect memory.

Edit: I'm trying to:

1. Get events by correlationId
2. Do a validation if next action is possible
3. Write new event in same stream with same correlationId

I don't want to perform optimistic locking on entire stream because then the same logic will fail for different correlationId if I do step one at the same time.

This seem to me as common feature of event sourcing that event store should support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed only do optimistic concurrency check on stream level
( i.e not on a derived stream created by the system projections)

Comment: could you share in more details what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: Hi I added what I'm trying to achieve in edit.

Comment: Example: I have transactions stream, transactions for same account are correlated with same correlationId. I want to check balance of my account before I do new transaction, then I would have to lock entire transactions stream, but I don't want to block transactions for other accounts.

Comment: Example 2: I want to allow user to update his profile once per day. I get last profile.updated event for user, check the time and then do update. I would have to do optimistic lock on entire profile stream instead only for profile with correlationId I want to update

Comment: in example 2 : 
"entire profile stream" is that for 1 profile , or all profiles ?

Comment: yes, sorry. I didn't realize that I should have stream per entity, for example, transactions.{accountId}. Thank you